# How to create a small file (size <= 2GB) file using application compiled with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64?

Tags: linux, posix, posix-api

When an application is compiled with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64 feature test macro, then all old 32-bit interface system calls (like creat/open/lseek, etc) will be replaced with new 64-bit interface system calls (like creat64/open64/lseek64,etc). So, the creat() call in my application creates a large file (size > 2GB). But, is it possible to create the small file (size <= 2GB) using same application compiled with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64?.

Comment: What makes you think that creat() will produce a file larger than 2GB in this case? This configuration changes the limits on the size of files that can be handled. From memory there are also some changes to the seek interface as well.

Comment: Keep in mind the only thing that changes with `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` is the range of the data (some hand waiving). With 32-bits, your data range is `[0, 2^32]`. With 64-bit, the datatype is twice as big, and your data range is `[0, 2^64]`. 0 is available on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines.

Comment: I am planning to write one small utility which reads the source file and duplicates it by creating/opening destination file and writing to it. When I make the utility large file aware using _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64, then the destination file after duplication can grow past 2GB if needed. Is it possible to create the destination file such that it will not grow beyond 2GB?

Answer (score 1):

> So, the creat() call in my application creates a large file (size > 2GB).

No, it doesn't. `creat()` always creates an empty file (or truncates an existing file).

Comment: What I meant was after creating the file and if I keep writing to it, it should not grow beyond 2GB.

Comment: If you don't want the file to grow larger than 2GB, then don't write more than 2GB to it?

Comment: I am looking forward to know whether it it is doable through some option during the creation of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `creat` wrapper function which is specifically compiled with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=32`.  This would give you a file descriptor which is limited to 32-bit file sizes.  However, this only works with certain 32-bit environments.

There is also `RLIMIT_FSIZE`, which can be set using `setrlimit`, but I have no idea how reliable it is.

Comment: Is there any open/create flag which limits the file size <= 2GB despite compiled with D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64? My requirement is that, application has to be large file aware, and  should dynamically decide whether to create small or large file.

Comment: Then you should look at `RLIMIT_FSIZE` and check if it works for your use case (or use a file system which is restricted to 31-bit file sizes, if something like that still exists). The non-large file support was only intended for ABI backwards compatibility (`sizeof (off_t)` should remain 4), and that's not a problem on 64-bit systems, so there is no way to open something like an *at most 2 GiB file*.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately RLIMIT_FSIZE does not work for my case,.